# App dev using PhoneGap, server storage queries/advice?

Tags: cordova, storage

I am building an app using PhoneGap and the web technologies. 
My goal: to generate data from a mobile device and tag it with a few tags and upload it to a server. Users should be able to call back the uploaded data filtering it by selecting a tag or tags.

I found plenty on local storage info and how-to's but its of no use in this case. I started reading about Jersey and Restlet but to a non-programmer, like myself, it seems a bit overwhelming. Lawnchair grabbed my eye and I read a lot about it but that also seems like a local storage solution.

My question: given the above criteria, bearing in mind, the simplicity, what is the fastest and most painless way of approaching this task in your opinion?

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? a database solution for phonegap.
Please add some more information.

Comment: Yes, Shank, a database solution for PhoneGap, the simplest possible! All I need it to do is tag an object, shuv it in the DB and then recall back the object based on the tags.

Comment: do you want to store the data on the device, or keep everything on your servers? or both?

you probably want something like backbone.js which hooks into a back end of your choosing. there are other options like parse.com in case you don't want to set up a back end.